# Google Analytics not giving consistent data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When i track events on analytics the data shown on the table at the bottom
and the data shown in the graph above the table is not consistent. Here is an example:

[15 events on firday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaDnR.png)

[40 events on Saturday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLIc1.png)

So as you can see the graph show 15 events on Friday and 40 on Saturday
so it is 55 events total, but the table shows 81 events in total.
Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total in the table is not what one would expect it to be. It is usually the sum of the numbers shown in the chart, but that would include duplicate counts. The chart above does not have the duplication.
For detailed explanation, you can see the Misunderstood Metrics article: 
http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-unique-events/

Comment: The thing is that sometimes the value in the table is lower then the value in the chart and sometimes higher. I read the article on the link you wrote and i still can't figure out why is this happening. You are saying that the data in the chart is accurate unlike the data in the table?

Comment: Yes, the data is the chart is not the same as the data at the top of the table. The chart is "right", the total in the table can be interpreted wrong -- sometimes it means the mathematical sum of the numbers below it, sometimes it means the deduplicated total, and sometimes it means the total of the Category you clicked on (when you click into a single category).

Comment: Thank you Mike.Too bad i was using the wrong data for the last year but at least i found out my (more accurate google) mistake.